# Why borders right and bottom are not displayed in a div with a SVG background?

Tags: css, svg, background-image, border

Can someone explain me why only the top and left borders are displayed on the div and img elements?

https://codepen.io/jpe44/pen/rNvbOdB

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='210' height='210' style='border: 3px dashed coral;'%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='100' r='100' fill='royalblue' style='filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px royalblue);' /%3E%3C/svg%3E">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert it to a "real" svg it seems to work. The border is there. What happens is that your svg image cannot be styled as `box-sizing:border-box` therefore image actual size is 210+3px*2 = 216px. How to remedy that? I don't know. But you can always style the `img` tag itself.

```css
img,
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
original:
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='210' height='210' style='border: 3px dashed red;'%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='100' r='100' fill='royalblue' style='filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px royalblue);' /%3E%3C/svg%3E">svg:
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='210' height='210' style='border: 3px dashed coral; '><circle cx='100' cy='100' r='100' fill='royalblue' style='filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px royalblue);' /></svg> img has border:
<img style='border: 3px dashed red;' src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='210' height='210' %3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='100' r='100' fill='royalblue' style='filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px royalblue);' /%3E%3C/svg%3E">
```

Comment: Yes, set a border on the `img` works as expected, but my questions concern the svg  _If you convert it to a "real" svg it seems to work_  
I don't understand what you mean. It doesn't seem to work any better !

Comment: I meant a `<svg>` element rather than `<img>` works, as the example show